# How to populate roles in firestore with react-redux-firebase package

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

So i'm using this package, and want to apply [this reciept](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/recipes/roles.html) to populate data from collection called 'roles' in my firestore to my firebase/profile data in redux state.

In this docs says, that my roles collection must be a sibling of users collection in firestore, but in my case it's not possible. I have different collections: Users, which stores data about users, and Roles, which stores app tree and access by roles.

How to populate data between different collections using this package? Please help me..

i'm using this code for setup:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {
      useFirestoreForProfile: true,
      userProfile: 'users',
      profileParamsToPopulate: [
      { child: 'profile', root: 'roles' }, //But that's not working because roles is not sibling of users
      ],
      attachAuthIsReady: true
    })
  )
)
```

Here is a screenshots of my data in firestore[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the **profile** field from string to **reference**. When making the profile field a reference then your data will be populated. When storing to a reference field you also need to include the collection in which the reference is. This means that the data in the profile field should look something like this **"roles/{roleId}"**, of course you should **replace {roleId}** with the id of the role you are trying to save in the profile field. In the first picture that you displayed the data in the profile field should look something like this: 'roles/q3Kb0dM2XBRzS4IIrDm'

P.S. If you add the reference field from code, use this line

> db.doc(`roles/${roleId}`)

db being your firestore object that you get by using **getFirestore()** in the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your code as per the [rrf docs's populate](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/populate.html) section with `useFirestoreForProfile` set to true, you'll see the following `console.warning`:

```
Profile population is not yet supported for Firestore
```

It seems like it's not supported right now

See [this](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/580) issue for more details